# how to shared data in constructor with other classes

Tags: vb.net, constructor, global-variables

I am studying VB.NET

I have a question about way to use data in constructor from other classes.

I tried to use "Public Shared" , however other classes do not recognize public shared constructor.

For example,

```
Public Class Main

  Public Shared GEN_SET As DB_GEN_SETTING

      Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
              ' Loading data to constructor in GEN_SET
          Set_XML_Load("SOME", GEN_SET)
      End Sub
  END CLASS

Public Class FrmControl_SET

    Public Sub Set_GEN(PRE As frmSet)
        Dim str As String = Main.GEN_SET.S_KEY ' this is actually working
        Dim str2 as string GEN_SET.S_KEY **' THIS IS NOT WORKING**
    End Sub

End Class
```

However, I am not really sure why "GEN_SET.KEY" is not working to get data from constructor

How can i share(or making it global) constructor ?

Comment: there are no constructors there.  if `DB_GEN_SETTING` is a Type, it is not instanced. since it isnt, whatever `S_KEY` is, isnt in existence yet.

Comment: Hi Plutonix// DB_GEN_SETTING is name of class. In the class , there is a constructor .......

Comment: it is never used because you never create an instance of of the class for the constructor to run

Comment: so ...  "Main.GEN_SET.S_KEY" is only way to look at the data(inside of constructor) from other classes ?

Comment: there is no data inside a constructor.  a ctor is the code that runs when a Type (Class/Object) is created. `.S_KEY` would appear to be a property and you cant access the property until you instance the `GEN_SET` variable.  Where appropriate, `GEN_SET = New DB_GEN_SETTING`, probably in that form load.  Al the code shown does is **declare** that GEN_SET will be of type DB_GEN_SETTING, it does not create an instance.  GEN_SET  need not be `Shared`